# Variables unknown after file rename

Tags: php, variables

I have the following problem.. 
I have a server.php file which is accessed via `index.php?page=server&pname=$1&port=$2` which shows all details about a server. 
Once I change the `server.php` file to like `test.php` and access it via  `index.php?page=test&pname=$1&port=$2` 
the whole file doesn't work as it says that many variables are unknown.. Has anybody dealt with something like this before?

A short snipped right from the top of the file:

```
<?php





if(empty($_GET['pname']) ||  !$server->exists) {
    $_SESSION['error'][] = $language['errors']['server_not_found'];
} else {

    /* Check if server is disabled */
    if(!$server->data->active) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = $language['errors']['server_not_active'];
    }

}

if(!empty($_SESSION['error']));



$result = $database->query("SELECT `id` FROM `points` WHERE `type` = 0 AND `server_id` = {$server->data->server_id} AND `ip` = '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}' AND `timestamp` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
if(!$result->num_rows) $database->query("INSERT INTO `points` (`type`, `server_id`, `ip`, `timestamp`) VALUES (0, {$server->data->server_id}, '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");


if($server->data->cachetime > time() - $settings->cache_reset_time) {


    $info = json_decode($server->data->details);

} else {


}


?>
```

Errors are:

> Notice: Undefined variable: server in
>   ++++ on line 7
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   ++++  on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: server_not_found in
>   ++++  on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: server in
>   ++++  on line 22
>   etc

After I rename the file, the $server variable is not usable anymore and even if i change it to the new filename it doesn't work. 
There are no includes where the $server variable could be declared.

I appreciate every kind of help!

Comment: You don't show where `$server` comes from so of course its undefined.

Comment: If the filename is server.php it works. The $server variable isn't declared anywhere separately.

Comment: Could you add the relevant parts of the index.php file. Especially all lines containing $_GET['page']. I suspect some implicit defininition like `${$_GET['page']} = new whatever()` is the reason for the different behaviour.

Comment: @jh1711
`if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
 $_GET['page'] = htmlspecialchars($_GET['page'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $pages = glob('pages/' . '*.php');
 $pages = preg_replace('(pages/|.php)', '', $pages);

 if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {
  include 'pages/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';
 } else {
  include 'pages/notfound.php';
 }
} else {
 include 'pages/home.php';
}`

Comment: @MoritzHupe I don't see anything in there that could define $server. Sorry I can't help. BTW when you post code it's frequently better to edit the question, and only add a short comment. That way you can use all formating tags.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a very unremarkable file where I had to change

```
$_GET['page'] == 'server'
```

to

```
$_GET['page'] == 'test'
```

A very silly mistake.

Thanks to everybody who helped!

@jh1711